# Triangle normal vs vertex normal

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, geometry, mesh

I can calculate *triangle* normal `N` by having three vertex positions of `v0`, `v1`, `v2` and using cross product:

[image: calculation]

The problem is a 3D mesh data structure needs a normal for each vertex. I mean, it needs `n1`, `n2` and `n3`. I don't know what is the correct way to calculate them.

#### Tried

I tried to use the same `N` value for `n1`, `n2` and `n3`, but I'm not sure if it is the correct approach:

`n1 = n2 = n3 = N`

Comment: If you want to compute a "smooth" mesh for a curved object (like a sphere), you have to interpolate the vertex normals from the adjacent face normals

Comment: @Rabbid76 Do you know any sample calculation I can get inspired by?

Comment: @user3405291 here is one of samples from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336175/how-can-i-optimize-my-soft-normal-calculation-function

Comment: @gkv311 Thanks! Exactly what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336810/3405291

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/2521214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented *smooth* vertex normal like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Vec3d> points = ...
std::vector<Vec3i> facets = ...

// Count how many faces/triangles a vertex is shared by
std::vector<int> counters;
counters.resize(points.size());

// Compute normals
norms.clear();
norms.resize(points.size());
for (Vec3i f : facets) {
    int i0 = f.x();
    int i1 = f.y();
    int i2 = f.z();
    Vec3d pos0 = points.at(i0);
    Vec3d pos1 = points.at(i1);
    Vec3d pos2 = points.at(i2);
    Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos0, pos1, pos2);
    
    // Must be normalized
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/3405291
    N.normalize();

    norms[i0] += N;
    norms[i1] += N;
    norms[i2] += N;

    counters[i0]++;
    counters[i1]++;
    counters[i2]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(norms.size()); ++i) {
    if (counters[i] > 0)
        norms[i] /= counters[i];
    else
        norms[i].normalize();
}
```