# Mesh color is messed up probably due to bad vertex normal computation

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, geometry, mesh

I have vertex *position* and *index* and I want vertex *normal*:

```cpp
// input
vector<Vec3f> points = ... // position
vector<Vec3i> facets = ... // index (triangles)

// output
vector<Vec3f> norms; // normal
```

#### Method 1

I compute normal like this:

```cpp
    norms.resize(points.size()); // for each vertex there is a normal

    for (Vec3i f : facets) {
        int i0 = f.x();
        int i1 = f.y(); // index
        int i2 = f.z();
        Vec3d pos0 = points.at(i0);
        Vec3d pos1 = points.at(i1); // position
        Vec3d pos2 = points.at(i2);

        Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos0, pos1, pos2); // face/triangle normal

        norms[i0] = N;
        norms[i1] = N; // Use the same normal for all 3 vertices
        norms[i2] = N;
    }
```

Then, the output mesh is rendered like this with a Phong material:

[image: Light and dark regions on final render]

#### Method 1 with reversed normal

When I reverse normal direction in method 1:

```
        norms[i0] = -N;
        norms[i1] = -N;
        norms[i2] = -N;
```

The dark and light regions are swapped:

[image: Swapped dark and light regions]

The same happens by swapping position 0 with position 1 by:

```
        // Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos0, pos1, pos2);
        Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos1, pos0, pos2); // Swap pos0 with pos1
```

#### Method 2

I compute the normal by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/3405291):

```cpp
    // Count how many faces/triangles a vertex is shared by
    vector<int> counters;
    counters.resize(points.size());

    norms.resize(points.size());
    for (Vec3i f : facets) {
        int i0 = f.x();
        int i1 = f.y(); // index
        int i2 = f.z();
        Vec3d pos0 = points.at(i0);
        Vec3d pos1 = points.at(i1); // position
        Vec3d pos2 = points.at(i2);
        
        Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos0, pos1, pos2);

        // Must be normalized
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/3405291
        N.normalize();

        norms[i0] += N;
        norms[i1] += N; // add normal to all vertices used in face
        norms[i2] += N;

        counters[i0]++;
        counters[i1]++; // increment count for all vertices used in face
        counters[i2]++;

    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/3405291
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(norms.size()); ++i) {
        if (counters[i] > 0)
            norms[i] /= counters[i];
        else
            norms[i].normalize();
    }
```

This method yields a totally dark final render by a Phong material:

[image: Totally dark]

I also tried methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336810/3405291) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336874/3405291) which are similar to method 2. They all result in a final render which looks like that of method 2 i.e. all dark regions without any light one.

#### Method 2 with reversed normal

I used method 2, but at the end, I reversed the normal direction by:

```
    for (Vec3d & n : norms) {
        n = -n;
    }
```

To my surprise, the final render is all darK:

[image: Still dark, despite reversed normal]

Also in method 2, I tried swapping position 0 with position 1:

```
        // Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos0, pos1, pos2);
        Vec3d N = triangleNormal(pos1, pos0, pos2); // swap pos0 with pos1
```

The final render is all dark regions without any light ones.

#### How?

Any idea how I can get my final render to be all light without any dark region?

Comment: btw is your `triangleNormal` working properly (assuming its using cross product to obtain the normal) and or are you passing 3D position into them? as your cylinders has the same color along circumference which hints they might not be 3D or correct

Comment: @Spektre `Vec3d MyClass::triangleNormal(Vec3d pos0, Vec3d pos1, Vec3d pos2)
{
    Vec3d V = pos1 - pos0;
    Vec3d W = pos2 - pos0;
    Vec3d N = V.cross(W);
    return N;
}`

Comment: That looks ok but I would add normalization so the normal is unit vector ... right now the returned vector has magnitude equal to double of the triangle's area which might also mess your lighting computations if not handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like your mesh does not have consistent winding rule. So some triangles/faces are defined CW other in CCW order of vertexes causing that some of your normals are facing in opposite direction. There are few things you can do to remedy:

1. **use double sided normals lighting**

   this is easiest... somwhere in fragment or wherever you are computing the shading something like this:

   ```
   out_color = face_color*(ambient_light+diffuse_light*max(0.0,dot(face_normal,light_direction)));
   ```

   when the normal is in wrong direction the result of `dot` is negative leading to dark color so just use `abs` value instead:

   ```
   out_color = face_color*(ambient_light+diffuse_light*abs(dot(face_normal,light_direction)));
   ```

   In fixed function pipeline there is even switch for this IIRC:

   ```
   glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
   ```
2. **repair mesh winding**

   there must be 3D tools to do this (Blender,3DS,...) or if your mesh is generated on the fly you could update your code to create consistent winding on your own.

   Correct winding enables you the use of `GL_CULL_FACE` which speeds up rendering considerably. Also it enables more advanced stuff like this:

   - [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)
3. **repair normals**

   In some cases there are ways to detect if the normal is pointing outwards or inwards to mesh for example like this:

   - [Determing the direction of face normals consistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57440487/2521214)

   So just negate the wrong ones during computation of normal and that is it. However if your mesh is too complicated (too far from convex) is this not so easily done as you need to use local "centers" of mesh or even inside polygon tests which are expensive.

The averaging method of generating normals gives you dark colors for both directions of normals which means you wrongly computed them and they are most likely zero. For more info about such approach see:

- [How to achieve smooth tangent space normals?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/2521214)

Anyway to debug problems like this its best to render your normals as lines going from the vertexes of your mesh (use wireframe). Then you would see directly what normals are good and bad. Here example:

[image: normals]

Comment: My problem is not fixed yet, but your post just makes sense =)