# How to replace a vertex normal by the average of its vertex normal neighbors?

Tags: opengl, normals

I'm writing an application in openGL. I want to implement very smooth toon shading.
I've read (and seen in Maya) that replacing the vertex normal with the average of its
vertex normals neighbors helps smoothing the shading. Is there a convinient way to do
it in OpenGL? I load the vertex normal for each vertex from the obj file, but I'm not
sure which vertex normals are neighbors...
Thanks!

Comment: Which language? Related: [How can I optimize my Soft Normal calculation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336175/how-can-i-optimize-my-soft-normal-calculation-function/61336810#61336810)

Comment: C++ and Glsl. From my understanding, the answer to the question in the link above suggests adding the face normal of each adjucent face to the vertex normal and then normalizing it. Will it work the same way as averaging the neighbor vertex normals?

Comment: No, the average is not a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector). (nva + nvb +nvc) / 3 != normalize(nva + nvb + nvc)

Comment: 1. neighboring faces are those that share at least one vertex so you average all faces normals that share at least one vertex ...